# How to send the foreach data from the model to the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am getting the Nameno from the database like below format.

```
$form_data['Nameno']='1,2,3,4';

$getName=$this->Home_model->getNameData($form_data['Nameno']);
```

Now I am passing that Nameno to the model to get the Name. So I used `explode` and passing to the foreach

**Model**

```
public function getNameData($NameId){

     $getTempid=explode(",",$NameId);

    $arrayData=[];
    foreach ($getTempid as $row){
    $where = array('is_tempActive' => 1,'Name_id'=>$row);

    $this->db->select('templateName');
    $this->db->from('tbl_templatename');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    //print_r($result);
    //$arrayData[]=$result;

    }
    return $result;
}
```

I need an output from my model like `$getName='ABC,XYZ,POD,RED'`

After suggested @Barmar answer

**controller**

```
$ids = explode(',', $form_data['Nameno']);
$names = array();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $names[] = $this->Home_model->getNameData($id)->templateName;;
   // print_r($names);
}

$getNames = implode(',', $names);
print_r($getNames);
```

**Model**

```
public function getNameData($tempId){

    $where = array('is_tempActive' => 1,'Name_id'=>$row);

    $this->db->select('templateName');
    $this->db->from('tbl_templatename');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

Would you help me out in this issue?

Comment: Put all the results in an array and use `implode()` to concatenate them into a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explode the original data into an array, call the function on each element, then implode the result back into a string.

```
$ids = explode(',', $form_data['Nameno']);
$names = array();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $nameData = $this->Home_model->getNameData($id);
    $names[] = $nameData[0]->templateName;
}
$getNames = implode(',', $names);
```

Comment: What should I use in the model?

Comment: I am getting error in the    $getNames = implode(',', $names); "Message: Array to string conversion"

Comment: I assumed that `getNameData()` returns the name as a string. If not, you need to extract the name before putting it into the `$names` array.

Comment: What I did, I display the print_r($names) inside foreach then I am getting the output.     Array( [0] => Array([0] => stdClass Object([templateName] => asdasdasdasdasdsadas) ))
    Array
    ([0] => Array ([0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [templateName] => asdasdasdasdasdasd
                    )
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [templateName] => adasdadadadadadsad
                    )
    
            )
    
    )

Comment: But when I am echo $getNames then I am getting the "Message: Array to string conversion"

Comment: One idea is to prepare the string you required on model and then only send to controller.

Comment: @jaydeepmarvaniya, Can you share some more details?

Comment: Don't you see that the names are in the `templateName` property? Just add that accessor to the code. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Barmar, Oh Sorry, I was trying from my side so I changed it and I forgot to update in the comment.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried again but I am getting the error" Message: Trying to get property 'templateName' of non-object"

Comment: Now I see, the object is wrapped in an array.

Comment: @Barmar, I just updated my code in the question. can you please check it it's correct or not?

Comment: You're missing `[0]` that I just added to my answer.

Comment: I think, this time it's working. Give me some time to check again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running multiple queries in a loop, you can use `where_in()` to get the results with one query.

```
public function getNameData($NameId){

    $getTempid = explode(",", $NameId);

    $this->db->select('Name');
    $this->db->from('tbl_templatename');
    $this->db->where('is_tempActive', 1);
    $this->db->where_in($getTempid);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
         $names[] = $row->Name;
    }
    return implode(',', $names);
}
```

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: I tried your code, I am getting the issue, Like I have 1,2 NameId. but I am getting all the list in the table. It should be displayed only 1,2 but it's displaying all the list